# NHibernate Fluent CompositeId with CustomType mapping

Tags: c#, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping

I have trouble creating the following mapping:

```
CompositeId(x => x.Id)
    .KeyProperty(x => x.SiteId, "SiteID")
    .KeyProperty(x => x.SomeId, "SomeId")
    .KeyProperty(x => x.AnotherId, "AnotherId")
    .KeyProperty(x => x.Dtg, "DTG");
```

Previously Dtg is not part of CompositeId so I can just put Dtg as:

```
Map(x => x.Dtg, "DTG").CustomType("DateTime2");
```

It requires DateTime2 as millisecond is required.

Now due to a change I will have to make Dtg as part of CompositeId.

So how do I put CustomType to Dtg? thanks for your help.

Comment: Maybe is it time to use a surrogate key, instead of going on with composite ones.

Comment: I've recommended replacing all composite key with surrogate key, but recommendation not taken :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solution found, adding `.CustomType<TimestampType>()` does not truncate  milliseconds:

```
CompositeId(x => x.Id)
.KeyProperty(x => x.SiteId, "SiteID")
.KeyProperty(x => x.SomeId, "SomeId")
.KeyProperty(x => x.AnotherId, "AnotherId")
.KeyProperty(x => x.Dtg, "DTG").CustomType<TimestampType>();
```